# Django - Page redirect showing as empty page after saving?

Tags: python, django, cs50

UPDATE: I'm trying to use HttpResponseRedirect() to guide the user back to the entry page but it's not working for me somehow with this syntax: `return HttpResponseRedirect((entry_page(request, title))`

I'm working through a Wiki project for CS50's web course and I'm having an issue with my edit entry implementation. I'm able to edit an entry and it saves properly but for some reason, redirecting the user to the newly edited entry is only showing an empty entry page like this:

[image: This shows up after I edit]

here's my views. py:

```
def edit(request, title):
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "title": title,
            "content": content
        })

    elif request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        content = request.POST.get("content")
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        html = md_converter(util.get_entry(title))
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "title": title,
            "content": html
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "title": title,
        })
```

and my urls.py:

```
from . import views

app_name = "encyclopedia"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry_page, name="entry"),
    path("wiki/edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("random", views.random_page, name="random"),
    path("create_landing",views.create_landing_page, name="create_landing"),
    path("create_entry",views.create_entry, name="create_entry")
]
```

Is there something wrong with my redirect? When I revisit the entry page, the page shows the edits I made

Thanks so much for reviewing.

Comment: You've provided everything but the code you have a problem with

Comment: The code I had a problem with was the edit function in views.py

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out,

I was rendering the page wrong and not providing the right variables to the context for `def edit`. I changed the `elif` statement in there to this instead and it worked:

```
elif request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        content = request.POST.get("content")
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        html = md_converter(util.get_entry(title))
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "title": title,
            "entry": html
        })
```